# R: Estimating Carma(2,1) parameters (using yuima package)

Tags: r, time-series

*(This was also posted on Quant.SX, but I'm not sure if this is a better place for it)*

I am very new to R, and particularly to the `yuima` package, so I was hoping someone would be able to help me.

I have some data (daily prices) that I wish to fit to a Carma(2,1) model by estimating the parameters.

Suppose I have

```
d <- read.csv("http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM&g=d&x=.csv")
```

What I then thought I should do is

```
library(yuima)
y <- setYuima(data = setData(d$Close), model = setCarma(2,1))
x <- qmle(y, start = list(a1 = 1, a2 = 1, b0 = 1))
```

(but with some other parameters).

However when I do this, I get the following error in the first (`y <- ...`) line:

```
Error in if (dim(data@original.data)[2] == 1) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I have no idea why this is, and what the `setYuima` function expects. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
library(xts)
library(yuima)
d <- read.csv("http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM&g=d&x=.csv", stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
d$Date <- as.Date(d$Date)
d.xts <- xts(d[,-1], d[,1])
y <- setYuima(data = setData(d.xts$Close), model = setCarma(2,1))
y
# Carma process p=2, q=1 with Levy jumps
# Number of equations: 3
# Number of Wiener noises: 1
# Parametric model with 6 parameters

# Number of original time series: 3
# length = 13577, time range [1962-01-02 ; 2015-12-07]

# Number of zoo time series: 3
#     length   time.min   time.max delta note
# x.1  13577 1962-01-02 2015-12-07     7    *
# x.2  13577 1962-01-02 2015-12-07     7    *
# x.3  13577 1962-01-02 2015-12-07     7    *
# ================
# * : maximal mesh
```